# Python CLI "-c" invalid syntax with Popen

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess, popen

I have a program where I need to check if a machine has all the Python module dependencies required. This machine may be a local machine or a remote machine. So, to generalize the code, I am executing system commands (so the script can be run from anywhere, connect to the machine and run the command)

If the python script is checking locally, it is running the following

```
cmd = "python -c \"import myRequiredModule\""
pg = Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True, executable="/path/to/powershell")
```

However the output is the following:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    import
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I simply open PowerShell and run it though, it seems to work okay. Why is this failing?

Comment: Shouldn't `stdout-subprocess.PIPE` be `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  Oh, sorry, that was just and error in copying. I will change it.

Comment: Hi @jay-s if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

You can use a requirements file and tell PIP to install what is missing by:

```
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You can write a Python program which will print out the missing modules:

```
from pkgutil import iter_modules
modules = set(x[1] for x in iter_modules())

with open('requirements.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        requirement = line.rstrip()
        if not requirement in modules:
            print requirement
```

Or you can write a Python program which will try to install missing modules by itself:

```
import pip

def import_or_install(package_name):
    try:
        __import__(package_name)
    except ImportError:
        pip.main(['install', package_name])
```